# Why does this CSV not be parsed with fgetcsv?

Tags: php, encoding, fgetcsv

I cannot parse a CSV file which is well formated. Could it be that it has something to do with encoding?
This is the Source:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen ("http://productdata.zanox.com/exportservice/v1/rest/20058589C1721570258.csv?ticket=A3AC91472561713FFB72A266542E9240AFE88CDE05D23B40B28B517606BE5D41&columnDelimiter=;&textQualifier=DoubleQuote&nullOutputFormat=NullValue&dateFormat=dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss&decimalSeparator=comma&gZipCompress=null&id&na&pp&df&ds&im&lk&sn","r");  

while ( ($data = fgetcsv ($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE ) {
  $num = count ($data);
  for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
    echo $data[$c].";";
  }
} 
?>
```

I guess, it has to do something with encoding.  Output is : **‹{¿{?×(ÄN¾R"0;**

This is the Running version:
[Problem with CSV](http://www.linsen-preisvergleich.com/admin/zanoxproblem.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newline character is the problem. You have unix chars, but you expect windows-style newlines.
I converted an test it with the given CSV file.

You can test the converted CSV file with windows newlines:
http://pastebin.com/9CK3JMRc

You could fix this in the by autodetection `ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);`
or convert the strings.