# Parsing UTF8 and other CSV files

Tags: php, parsing, csv

i have CSV Files which i read by: [Why does this CSV not be parsed with fgetcsv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125523/why-does-this-csv-not-be-parsed-with-fgetcsv)

But now there are some,, which are UTF8 and some not,...how can i implement an "auto detection"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this php function: [mb_detect_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php)

It does what the name stands for: detecting character encoding.